# Image Rotation in Query and Chrome

Tags: jquery, image, css, rotation

I have script to rotation images. It works in other browsers but in Google Chrome doesn't work.

I found trick in CSS3 but in IE I can't to rotation image 10 degrees:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this for cross-browsing:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-10deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-10deg);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove the comment in your CSS:

```
 /*-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
```

It should be:

```
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
```

Comment: This is good idea, but in IE is working bad... Here is example: http://demo.spisula.pl/index.htm